# Square key is not working anymore in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have been using these hotkeys for a while now

```
        ² & WheelDown::AltTab ;; <-- AltTab with mouse
        ² & WheelUp::ShiftAltTab ;; <-- AltTab with mouse
```

Since last monday it is not working anymore and I have this message raising up

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are saving the ahk script as Unicode.
AHK only parses ASCII.

Open your script in Microsoft Notepad, and "save-as"
under Encoding: select "ANSI"

I tested your code, and I get a different error about not having the ² key in my keyboard layout when saving as ANSI. I get the same error when I save it as UTF-8

Upon testing a custom keyboard layout, I am able to use the script with no error after saving the ahk file as type ANSI, having remapped my 2 key to ²

---

**UTF-8:**

[image: image of AHK error with UTF-8 Encoding indicating invalid hotkey]

---

**ANSI:**

[image: image of AHK error with ANSI Encoding indicating ² key doesn't exist in keyboard layout]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help as I don't have a ² key, but you may find what you need in AHK moderator's response here...
[² key mapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=65194).

Comment: I will look into it, thx